# Visual studio package manager console not opening

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013

i get this error when trying to open package manager console

**The mandatory value ApplicationBase is not specified for registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine.**

also when trying to add nuget packages i get

**Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.**